# Tag merge linq2twitter and linq-to-twitter

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

See tags here:
[Find all followers for a user using Linq to Twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724064/find-all-followers-for-a-user-using-linq2twitter)

I think those two tags should be merged to the actual name of the library: `linq2twitter`

Answer (score 4):

The actual name of the library is not "linq2twitter", it's [LINQ to Twitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com) (in the same vein as LINQ to SQL, LINQ to XML, LINQ to Objects, etc). On the other hand, "linq2twitter" seems to be nothing more than a stylized logotype for the project.

Anyway, I retagged the two [linq2twitter](/questions/tagged/linq2twitter) questions and made it a synonym of [linq-to-twitter](/questions/tagged/linq-to-twitter).

Comment: Thanks, feel free to edit the question! :)